# How to inverse selection in Blender 2.8?

Tags: edit-mode

In the older versions of Blender I just have to tap  Ctrl+I to inverse the selection,but I didn't find it in the 2.8 version,is it possible to do that in another way,or where can I find it in the interface?

Comment: It's still CTRL + I in both object and edit mode if you're using Blender 2.80 default keymap. You can also find it in the *Select* menu.